# Struts2 won't find certain action

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles

First of all, and to avoid de duplicate question tag, my problem is that I have 4 different struts2 action calls. 3 of them work perfectly but the forth one just keeps unable to find the dispacher. Now the original question:

I have a dinamic web project running with struts2 as backend. I also use tiles for the header and nav bar. There are 4 buttons in the map, and 3 of them work perfectly. But when it comes to the forth one, the dispatcher fails and even the custom 404 page won't come up.

My struts.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="main" method="gotoMain" class="controller.NavActions">
            <result name="main" type="tiles">/tiles.main</result>
            <result name="error">/utils/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="arrive" method="gotoArrive" class="controller.NavActions">
            <result name="arrive" type="tiles">/tiles.arrive</result>
            <result name="error">/utils/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="depart" method="gotoDepart" class="controller.NavActions">
            <result name="depart" type="tiles">/tiles.depart</result>
            <result name="error">/utils/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="finder" method="gotoFinder" class="controller.NavActions">
            <result name="finder" type="tiles">/tiles.finder</result>
            <result name="error">/utils/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="find_flight" method="findFlight" class="controller.NavActions">
            <result name="find" type="tiles">/tiles.find.flight</result>
            <result name="error">/utils/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

The navigator html is the next one, with the struts prefix being 's':

```
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav">
        <li id="main" class="nav-item"><s:a action="main">
                <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </s:a></li>
        <li id="depart" class="nav-item"><s:a action="depart">
                <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Departures</span>
            </s:a></li>
        <li id="arrive" class="nav-item"><s:a action="arrive">
                <i class="fa fa-plane fa-rotate-90" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Arrivals</span>
            </s:a></li>
        <li id="finder" class="nav-item"><s:a action="finder">
                <i class="lnr lnr-magnifier"></i>
                <span>Finder</span>
            </s:a></li>
    </ul>
```

The dispacher fails somewhere here, does not reach Java method. I'm not posting the Java code because it simply returns the needed string and changes a field. The tomcat console error is the next one:

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó una excepción

The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using 
Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable 
when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which 
initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown 
location]
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
at org.apache.jsp.utils.error_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f0(error_jsp.java:193)
at org.apache.jsp.utils.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:153)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:442)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ene 15, 2017 12:12:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
GRAVE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/utils/error.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:560)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:442)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
at org.apache.jsp.utils.error_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f0(error_jsp.java:193)
at org.apache.jsp.utils.error_jsp._jspService(error_jsp.java:153)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
... 24 more
```

The hole set of actions work fine, but when it comes to finder, the dispacher crashes. If I introduce the action in the URL back again, it will work, but when I try again, pops up the error once more.

Comment: You're hitting a JSP page directly w/o going through an action.

Comment: No, I'm not. I was going through an action and doing it right. It was just the tomcat, doing weird stuff.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml

Comment: As I commented up there, I solved it just by killing tomcat, removing all the config files, reinstalling other version and relaunching it. I a little overkill, it must be enough if you just reset the server.